# Change Div Content with another file using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

how i can change div content with jquery if i click content in sidenav and 'div id="isi"' content change in another file.

```
<div id="mySidenav" class="sidenav">
  <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="closebtn" onclick="closeNav()">&times;</a>
  <a href="about.html">About</a>
  <a href="#">Services</a>
  <a href="#">Clients</a>
  <a href="#">Contact</a>
</div>


<section id="main">

  <div>
    <span style="font-size:30px;cursor:pointer" onclick="openNav()">&#9776; </span>
  </div>

  <div class="row" id="isi">

  </div>
```

sorry my English so bad

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like this should work

```
$.ajax({
   method: 'GET',
   url: 'otherfile.html',
}).done(function(data) {
   $('#isi').html(data);
})
```